# how to encode and decode pdf files using base64encode/decode ( windows app store )in c#

Tags: winrt-xaml, winrt-async

solution with sample using c#,
scenario:
Download encoded  pdf file of base64Encode and decode(base64Decode) and store in  ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

Answer (score 0):

you can use File.ReadAllBytes to load the PDF file into your program and then u can convert the loaded pdf file using Convert.ToBase64String(bytes) method

You might want to prefer this link

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/e5965e02-0bbb-4f8d-9e5f-8611aa902457/how-to-convert-pdf-file-to-base64binary

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not going to write a solution with a complete sample for you, but I will point you to what may be the most exhaustive base42 discussion in Windows Runtime.

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/11/reading-and-writing-base64-in-windows.html

It's a crazy coincidence that I just wrote this a few weeks ago. You'll notice that it is in the context of an image, but you should be able to translate it simple enough.

Remember to post your solution here!

Best of luck!